# Get acknowledgment of print from a printer

Tags: java, printing, command

I am using the following code to give print to a network `Lipi` Printer (***cc2*** is printer name)

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("lp -dcc2 abcd.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (
    new InputStreamReader (p.getInputStream ()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
    System.out.println (line);
}
```

The problem starts when I run this in loop(> 4000) and a few of the prints get lost in the network and don't get printed.

I want to catch those lost prints and reprint them.

How can I get the printer to acknowledge the print has been received.

Answer (score 1):

Check manual for your implementation of `lp` command.  Some implementations can notify when printing is done, but the form of such notification may vary.  Also there is `-m` switch that tells `lp` to send an e-mail to a user who initiated printing, once printing is done.  Maybe you can somehow check these e-mails from your Java application.  Anyway, this question is more about printing system of your OS rather than about Java.